# Java- Regex for a string not containing a substring followed by any characters

Tags: java, regex

I want to find a regex in Java for a Windows Server 2008 OS version which does not contain "R2"
Regex I am currently using -

```
(?i)Win\w*\s*(?i)Server\s*(2008)\s*(?!R2)\s*\w*
```

Possible values:

- `Windows Server 2008 datacenter`  - Matches correctly
- `Windows Server 2008`             - Matches correctly
- `Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter` - Does not match
- `Windows Server 2008 r2 datacenter` - Does not match
- `Windows Server 2008 R2`           - **Matches incorrectly (because `R2` fits into `\w*` in the regex)**

What am I doing wrong in the regex?

Comment: Remove the `\s*` after your lookahead. Are you using this in context of `String matches()`?

Comment: No. I am using pattern.matcher from java.util.regex.
But removing \s worked for regex matcher too. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider using the following *regex* :

```
(?i)Win\w*\s*Server\s*(2008)(?!\sR2).*?$
```

see **[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/htBpfK/2)**

**Java** ( [demo](https://ideone.com/ck07YG) )

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class RegEx {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "Windows Server 2008 datacenter";
        String r = "(?i)Win\\w*\\s*Server\\s*(2008)(?!\\sR2).*?$";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(r);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression to match string if it contains R2

```
private boolean isR2(String text) {
         return (text.toLowerCase().matches(".*r2.*"));
    }
```

without regular expression, you can do

```
private boolean isR2(String text) {
     return (text.toLowerCase().indexOf("r2")>0);
}
```

both match all your examples correctly:

- `Windows Server 2008 datacenter // false`
- `Windows Server 2008 //false`
- `Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter //true`
- `Windows Server 2008 r2 datacenter //true`
- `Windows Server 2008 R2 //true`